# Download angular page on demand. Hybrid application (SPA+MPA)

Tags: angular, reactjs, express, single-page-application

How to make angular application which load few pages at the beginning. 
Like I have a web application which compiles and generates a 25 MB build. But I want to segregate it and move few component which will be loaded once that URL is visited or invoked. Also the same web-page will never be cached.

So is there any possibility to achieve it in angular and download the content(html and js file) on demand.
Application is running in Express (nodejs).
**The first landing page should be downloaded when the page is visited for the 1st time and in the background I want to load other pages gradually. So that I can distribute the download limit**

Scenario is used for pagination: On loading page1: page 2,3,4 and 5 will be cached. And on page 17: page 12 to page 22 will be cached/download in the browser. All the pages have different content, so I can't achieve it just by data manupulation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Angular it can be achieved using the concept LazyLoading. Where only the necessary pages are loaded initially and the lazy loaded modules are loaded on demand when tries to access the page
Check the link attached below.

[Lazy Loading Concept](https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules)

Comment: Ok. You mean that I need to skip that component from NgModules?

Comment: You need to separate components into a module and add module as lazy load(Refer link) in Angular Routing Module. When you build in production mode. You can see the separate chunks of .js created for lazy loaded modules.